# Classes Representing Tables Where Behavior Needs To Vary By Row

Tags: java, design-patterns, orm, oop

My title is a bit vauge,  here's the problem I'm talking about.

Say I have:

```
class Bill
{
   public String legislationID;
   public BillStatus currentStatus;
}

//and

class BillStatus
{
   public String description; 
}
```

When persisted, BillStatus corresponds to a table with one row per possible state of a piece of legislation. (e.g. "On House Floor", "On Senate Floor", etc).

The problem I always run into is this:

As soon as behavior starts to vary based on which instance of BillStatus is attached to Bill, the whole thing becomes hard to represent.  I see two options:

1) A lot of switches in Bill that branch behavior depending on current BillStatus
  2) methods in bill status that accept Bill as a parameter, and have switches that execute different logic depending on identity of instance.  (so kind of mimicking classes implementing a common interface)

Both these methods seem sloppy.  What I would like to be able to do is this:

```
class abstract BillStatus
{
    public abstract String getDescription();
    public abstract void callForVote(Bill bill);
}
```

Then:

```
@SpecialEntityTag(whenRowValue="HOUSEFLOOR")
class BillStatusHouseFloor extends BillStatus
{
     /* special overrides for some methods */     
}

class BillStatusGeneric extends BillStatus
{
    /* standard implementation of BillStatus */
}
```

This has to be a common problem.  Am I thinking about it the wrong way?  Basically the goal is to encapsulate behavior that changes with particular value of a non-primitive child property.

Comment: Another solution that doesn't quite work:  sub classes of Bill for each particular state bill can be in.  This doesn't work in my case because there are at least 3 state-like properties that affect Bill's behavior.  This seems to mean that I would need [count of property 1]*[count of property2]*[count of property 3] subclasses of bill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What prevents you from using your design?

Hibernate (or JPA in general) is able to handle inheritance, and you may store a whole inheritance hierarchy in a single table with a discriminator column telling which subclass to use for a particular row.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#inheritance-tableperclass for details.

Comment: Heh I had a bit of a facepalm moment there.  I should probably hold off on the late night programming.    Thanks!